# Android Viewpager and PagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am working Viewpager with Pager indicator to display calendar. I am trying to setCurrentItem(1) in my adapter but it could not load the item 1 .In the oncreate method I have call the adapter.The below line is to call the adapter.

```
monthAdapter = new MonthPagerAdapter();
monthPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.monthpager);
monthPager.setAdapter(monthAdapter);
monthPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
monthPager.setCurrentItem(1);


public class MonthPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    ViewPager container;
    private MonthView addMonthViewAt(int position, Time time){
        final MonthView mv = new MonthView(HistoryMonthActivity.this);
        mv.setLayoutParams(new ViewSwitcher.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mv.setSelectedTime(time);
        this.container.addView(mv, position);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.i("setTime", "gg");
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
         ((ViewPager) container).removeViewAt(position);
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        this.container = (ViewPager) container;
        final Time time = new Time();
        time.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.month += (position - 1);
        time.normalize(true);
        return addMonthViewAt(position, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code monthAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();it will show the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0

Comment: If u give me  your mail id I will send my project code to you. please help me...